# How to split strings from a CSV column into a list?

Tags: string, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to make a list out of the words of a CSV column called 'text' that is composed of strings

This is what I have:

```
def html_words():

    legits_text = pd.read_csv('/Users/pmpilla/Documents/phishing/html_text.csv', delimiter=',')

    list_text = legits_text["text"].split(" ")
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pmpilla/Documents/phishing/html_words/legit_path_words.py", line 70, in <module>
    html_words()
  File "/Users/pmpilla/Documents/phishing/html_words/legit_path_words.py", line 30, in html_words
    list_text = legits_text["text"].split(" ")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3614, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you might need to do is:

```
list_text = legits_text["text"].str.split(" ")
```

you might also need to use the parameter `expand=True` to create new columns instead of a list.
Refer:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html